# How to compile QGIS from source with Grass?

Tags: qgis, gdal, grass-gis, ubuntu

I recently decided to reinstall QGIS and build against the latest version of GDAL - something I have been putting off for ages because I suspected it would be a nightmare. Lo and behold it has been, so after a full-day of trying to get this to compile following these: [instructions](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL) I'm reaching out for some help.

I successfully built GDAL 2.0 this morning (at least I think it was successful `gdalinfo --version` is now showing `GDAL 2.0.0, released 2015/06/14` and have been working my way through the instructions above.

I'm currently stuck at 47% with make failing here:

```
[ 47%] Built target qgis.d.rast7
Linking C executable ../../../../output/lib/qgis/grass/modules/qgis.g.info7
/usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRGetLinearUnits@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRExportToWkt@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRGetAttrValue@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `SetCSVFilenameHook@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRExportToProj4@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRMorphFromESRI@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRExportToPrettyWkt@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRMorphToESRI@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRImportFromProj4@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRDestroySpatialReference@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `VSIFree@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRIsProjected@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRNewSpatialReference@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRIsGeographic@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRGetUTMZone@GDAL_1.8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [output/lib/qgis/grass/modules/qgis.g.info7] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/providers/grass/7/CMakeFiles/qgis.g.info7.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm not quite sure what this means - though some searching suggests I may still have an old install of GDAL lurking, though not sure I can find it - as I removed a couple earlier when make failed much earlier on.

I thought it could be something to do with Grass 7 which I installed following these [enter link description here](http://grass.osgeo.org/download/software/linux/) instructions. But I've also tried to compile with `GRASS_PREFIX7` set to `OFF` in `ccmake`. But make fails at the same place.

p.s. using:
Ubuntu 14.04
GRASS7
GDAL 2.0

Comment: You should use linux utilities `ldd` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ldd_%28Unix%29), `nm` and `readelf` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732/how-do-i-list-the-symbols-in-a-so-file to try to follow and understand where the bug can come from.

Answer (score 1):

If you build gdal yourself, you should also build grass yourself.

Using grass binaries which are linked against a different version of gdal than QGIS is certainly a very bad idea.

Comment: Yea, from glancing at the OPs errors it looks like GRASS just needs to be re-compiled against the updated GDAL they installed first.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was related to the flags in `cmake`. My purpose was not related to GRASS 7 so I just had to desactivate it.

My line for compiling is similar to below (I didn't provide all the options just the ones related to GRASS)

```
cmake -DWITH_GRASS=OFF -DWITH_GRASS7=OFF ..
```

You need to do before a

```
make clean
```

You can also check if your configuration related to GRASS is effective looking at generated file `CMakeCache.txt`. It should contain something like below:

```
...
//Determines whether GRASS 6 plugin should be built
WITH_GRASS:BOOL=OFF

//Determines whether GRASS 7 plugin should be built
WITH_GRASS7:BOOL=OFF
...
```

Comment: thanks for the comments @ThomasG77 - thing is I want to build QGIS against GRASS as I need GRASS plugin support in QGIS. I have managed to get this compiled without GRASS but missing the plugins:(